# i don't know how i should display this bug but here it is

Tags: batch-file, cmd

i don't know how i should display this problem but here it is:

```
@echo off
:mmm
set mmm=<mmm.txt
set /a m2m=%mmm%+1
echo %m2m% > mmm.txt
echo %m2m%
pause
goto mmm
```

i want it to go 1,2,3,4,5.. se also my other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24273003

Comment: i'm not sure but try to remove your @echo off string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with :

```
set /p mmm=<mmm.txt
```

Comment: you just fixed a whole software dude, let me buy you a pizza on just-eat :D